# Eliminar todas las comas de un patrón con sed pero no de toda la línea

Tags: linux, bash, sed

Estoy intentando eliminar las comas de las líneas en un **csv**, pero solo quiero eliminar las que tengo dentro de un patrón y no de toda la línea. El problema es que el numero de comas dentro de ese patrón va cambiando según la línea y si uso el `/g` al final no me respeta el patrón buscado y me borra todas las comas de la línea.

Ejemplo:

```
945,"Hey You, Pikachu!",N64,1998,Simulation,Nintendo,0.83,0.06,0.93,0,1.83

1835,"The Game (XBox 360, PS2, PS3, PC Versions)",PS2,2007,Action,Activision,0.63,0.37,0,0.11,1.11
```

Lo que necesito es eliminar las comas que estan en la segunda columna, es decir todas las comas que se encuentran entre las `" "`. Tengo esto:

```
sed -i '/"*"/s/,/ /g' fichero.csv
```

También he probado encadenando comandos

```
grep -E '"*"' fichero.csv | cut -d'"' -f2 | sed -i 's/,/ /g' fichero.csv
```

De esta segunda forma en teoría selecciono solo el texto del patrón y le quito las comas, pero igual me lo aplica a la línea entera.

¿Alguien que me pueda ayudar?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: creo que es un trabajo para un lenguaje que tenga un intérprete de CSV más potente, pues hacerlo con shell scripting implica gestionar toda la casuística. Con Python sería muy rápido, por ejemplo

Answer (score 0):

Lo mejor es usar un lenguaje de progamacicón que permita parsear CSV con algún módulo. Pero si el fichero siempre tiene ese formato, podrías usar esto:

```
perl -i -pe 's/,(?!")(?=.*")//' fichero.csv
```

La expresión regular explicada:

```
,                  # una coma
(?!")              # no precedida inmediatamente de "
(?=.*")            # precedida por alguna "
```

Debería funcionar siempre que tu columna tipo string entrecomillada esté en la primera o segunda posición y sea la única columna entrecomillada, que parece ser tu caso.

Tienes una demo [aquí](https://regex101.com/r/qUgLzg/1)